# Selenium cant access any elements on the webpage

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium

I'm writing Selenium tests in C# with Specflow and Nunit for a new project i'm working on and nothing inside the `body` can be selected anywhere at all

[image: Divs I am trying to interact with:]

I **can** access body with

```
WaitUntil(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("body")));
```

but  **can not** of the following work and throe element not found exceptions:

```
WaitUntil(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("halo-root")));
WaitUntil(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("halo-entry")));`
WaitUntil(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("halo-navigation-container")));
```

etc

> error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"halo-root"}

- There are no iframes
- I have tried long waits to ensure its nothing asynchronous
- the website is angular.js (I have tried some protractor approaches but nothing successfully)
- I've also played around wit `ElementIsVisible`, `ElementIsClickable` etc
- Ive tried different selectors (id, className, xpath etc)

All help appreciated

p.s cant share the entire SUT as it required vpn access.

Comment: The may be JAVA running and you have to wait for the JAVA to complete. So yo umay have to loop until the element is not null.

Comment: Can you post the url if it is public?

Comment: "<HALO" is not HTML, but rather a place-holder that is likely replaced via Javascript (JAVA is a different language, btw...)  This could also be a data structure used by the actual web page and not the page itself... Inspect the element you are targeting at the time you will be retrieving it to find it's true markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was when logging in through a portal (Jumpcloud) a new tab was opened (that I didn't notice) so the solution was just switch to that new window with `_driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles[1])`

Thanks for all the help though! :)

Answer (score 1):

First check your html. i think body tag must be present in **iframe**.
If it is present in iframe first switch to iframe  then try any commands(wait or actions) on element.